# Create a trusted ssl handshake with server using Java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, apache-axis

I need help creating a trusted connection with a web service using Axis2 and org.jsslutils.sslcontext.X509SSLContextFactory.  I have a generated client cert from the web service's admin console (client.p12).  I also have grabbed the server's public cert by going to the endpoint uri and exporting it to a file using the browser (pubserver.cer). I converted the client.p12 to a jks using keytool (mywsks.jks). I also imported pubserver.cer into the keystore.  I'm very new to ssl.  Do I need to import these certs into .../jre/lib/security/cacert or cacerts or trusted.libraries or can I just reference mywsks.jks? How do I set up my code for the server to trust me using X509SSLContextFactory?  It appears to need a keyStore and a trustStore which I'm deriving from this example:

```
X509SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = new X509SSLContextFactory( 
    keyStore, keyStorePassword, trustStore);
```

I'm currently using this to create the keyStore and trustStore:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");     
String keyStoreFile = "mywsks.jks"; 
InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
String keyStorePassword = "thepassword"; 
keyStore.load(keyInput, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
keyInput.close();

String trustStoreFile = "/path/to/cacert"; 
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyInput = new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile);
String trustStorePassword = "thepassword";
trustStore.load(keyInput, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
keyInput.close();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add your client certificate that is used for authenticate into web service into a keyStore(client.p12).
2. Add the server's public key(pubserver.cer) into your trustStore. It can be /jre/lib/security/cacert

Could you post what issue you are facing ? Because according to me, it is a confusing and a big topic to discuss..

This example will help you implementing this..

http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/ApacheHttpClientUsage

And finally you could make an URL connection..

Comment: My question was mainly about how to set the keyStore/trustStore variables and which cert to put where.  I think you may have answered that.  I'm going to try it out.

Comment: @Sravana Kumar I put the pubserver.cer in cacert.  I converted the client.p12 into mywsks.jks.  Please see the edits I've made for the results.

Comment: the first issue I had was that my jks and p12 did not have the same password.  That is apparently important when converting the p12 to jks.  The second issue I had was solved by putting the pubserver.cer into the the /jre/lib/security/cacert.  Thanks so much.  My issue is resolved.

Comment: Cool.. Also there is no need of converting your p12 keystore into jks. You can get an instance using `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")`. What happens internally is, server gives public key, client verifies with trust store, then client supplies certificate for authentication, server verifies it with keystore which is in server. And one more info : You may need to change the keystore periodically till your project completed. So remember the steps :)